# How do I access an array of Maps sent to a JSP via Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jstl

In a java command, I'm putting some Maps into a [TypedProperty](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZLC2_7.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.api.doc/com/ibm/commerce/datatype/TypedProperty.html) like so:

```
private TypedProperty populateOrderItemsDataStructure(TypedProperty tp)
{   
    final String METHODNAME = "populateOrderItemsDataStructure";
    if (LoggingHelper.isEntryExitTraceEnabled(LOGGER)) {
        LOGGER.entering(CLASSNAME, METHODNAME);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < orderItems.size(); i++)
    {
        Map orderItemsMap = new HashMap();
        String orderItemsString = orderItems.get(i).toString().substring(1, orderItems.get(i).toString().length() - 1); //convert to string and remove brackets
        while(true)
        {
            int firstNewline = orderItemsString.indexOf("\n");
            if(firstNewline <= 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            String thisItem = orderItemsString.substring(0, firstNewline);
            thisItem = thisItem.trim();

            String itemKey = thisItem.substring(0, thisItem.indexOf("="));
            String itemVal = thisItem.substring(thisItem.indexOf("=") + 1);

            orderItemsMap.put(itemKey, itemVal);                

            orderItemsString = orderItemsString.substring(firstNewline + 1);            
        }
        String oiKey = "orderItem" + i;
        tp.put(oiKey, orderItemsMap);
    }

    if (LoggingHelper.isEntryExitTraceEnabled(LOGGER)) {
        LOGGER.exiting(CLASSNAME, METHODNAME);
    }

    return tp;
}
```

I do this, and then attach them to a [SendMsgCmd](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZLC2_7.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.api.doc/com/ibm/commerce/messaging/commands/SendMsgCmd.html) like so:

```
SendMsgCmd cmdSendMsg = (SendMsgCmd)CommandFactory.createCommand("com.ibm.commerce.messaging.commands.SendMsgCmd", storeId);

TypedProperty tp = new TypedProperty(); 
tp = populateOrderItemsDataStructure(tp);       
cmdSendMsg.compose(null, getCommandContext(), tp);
```

which I can later finish up with

```
cmdSendMsg.execute();
```

This runs and works perfectly and outputs a JSP to an html file.

My problem is I have no idea how to access these Maps in my JSP.

This is the structure of the data after doing the `cmdSendMsg.compose(null, getCommandContext(), tp);` according to Eclipse:

[image: data structure]

So I'm trying to gain access to the data inside cmdSendMsg -> composeCommandParms -> elementData in my JSP, but I cannot figure out how to do it.  I'm trying things along the lines of

```
<c:forEach var="orderItem" items="${ composeCommandParms.elementData }" >
    <c:forEach var="orderItemParam" items="${ orderItem }">
        <p>${ orderItemParam.key}:&nbsp${ orderItemParam.value }</p>
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

But no matter what I try to put in the first items=${}, it's empty.  Interestingly enough, if I just do `${ orderItem0 } on my JSP, it prints out all of the data for orderItem0.  But I want to be able to iterate through a list of order items, which is why I have structured the data this way.  Can someone help me figure out how to access the list of these order items?

Comment: Have you tried `composeCommandParms.entrySet()`? It should return `Set` of key/value pairs you could iterate over: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#entrySet()

Comment: Your question is confusing, but at least `Hashtable.elementData` isn't a public field. If `${composeCommandParms}` implements `Map` (as confirmed by debug screen), then you must be able to just use `items="${composeCommandParms}"` right away.